# Insert content to Wordpress post editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I'm making a Wordpress plugin for adding image maps in the posts. Currently I have implemented the image maps as a custom post types. However I'm having some trouble with adding them in posts.

I have made a new tab in the media insert/upload window called Image map. When you click an image map in the tab, this function is fired:

```
function insertImageMap() {
    tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content',
    'some text or html code'
    );
    window.parent.tb_remove();
}
```

However nothing is added to the tinyMCE editor. The function is fired, but the instance of tinyMCE editor is undefined even if I use tinyMCE.getInstanceById('content'). Is there a way to access the editor of a post editor page?

I have included tinyMCE script in my plugin and it doesn't show as undefined.

I found an older question asking the same, but the answer wasn't very helpful:
[Custom Wordpress Plugin - How do I insert content from popup on post editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457162/custom-wordpress-plugin-how-do-i-insert-content-from-popup-on-post-editor)

Comment: I think that it's because the pop-up is actually an iframe. So in order to access the `tinyMCE` instance, you need to get it through either `window.opener` or `window.parent`(I'm not 100% sure if it's any of those or something else). So you can do `var instance = window.opener.tinyMCE || window.parent.tinyMCE; instance.execInstanceCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content', 'some text or html code');`. In addition you can look through the source code(most-likely the JS) and see how WordPress sends the content to the editor.

Comment: Actually have you tried [`window.send_to_editor()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-admin/js/media-upload.dev.js)?

Comment: Well, the script isn't actually run in iframe. I can access the instance of tinyMCE itself, but not the post editor with tinyMCE.getInstanceById().

Comment: But you said that you added a new tab to the Media upload pop-up, and this is loaded in an iframe. Unless you're doing something really strange, it should be in an iframe. Please try `window.send_to_editor('content to go to editor here')` and tell me if it works.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood something. I had previously tested send_to_editor, but it had been undefined. Window.parent.send_to_editor did the trick though. Feels great when you miss obvious solutions like this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution found in comments:

```
function insertImageMap() {
    window.parent.send_to_editor('any text');
    window.parent.tb_remove();
}
```